# How To Implement SSL on Django?

Tags: ssl, https

After researching for a few hours, I have still no idea and confused to what is needed and the steps to implement HTTPS?

Can anyone enlighten me on what is needed and the STEPS to implement SSL?

Comment: there are answers for your question on stack already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131727/django-and-ssl-question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you're referring to (eventually) existing questions or information, share your research with proper references and explanations why existing solutions don't work _or_ (much less preferred) remove the notion that those exist since users have to do this work for you instead or will (much more likely) downvote your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django and SSL question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131727/django-and-ssl-question)